# how to avoid git-apply changing line endings

Tags: git, newline, eol

I have a git repo set with `core.eol=crlf`, `core.autocrlf=true` and `core.safecrlf=true`.

When I apply a patch from another `crlf` repo and to my repo all the line endings for the effected file are changed to `lf`. Currently I'm applying the patch as so:

```
git apply --ignore-whitespace mychanges.patch
```

(It seems I have to use `--ignore-whitespace` to get the patch to successfully apply.)

My current work around is to run `unix2dos` on the file. Is there a better way of getting apply to conform to my eol settings?

Answer (score 4):

Check if the issue persists with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2015)

See [commit c24f3ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c24f3abaceabb590125751a67ec0e32946780ac7) (19 Aug 2017), and [commit 2fea9de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fea9de61857986431982ae89c01c89a2fc10038) (13 Aug 2017) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a17483f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a17483fcfe313e9ff5b9b0eb8245605fe7f66ea7), 27 Aug 2017)</sup>

> ### `apply`: file committed with CRLF should roundtrip diff and apply
>
> When a file had been committed with CRLF but now `.gitattributes` says "`* text=auto`" (or `core.autocrlf` is `true`), the following does not
>   roundtrip, `git apply` fails:

```
printf "Added line\r\n" >>file &&
git diff >patch &&
git checkout -- . &&
git apply patch
```

> Before applying the patch, the file from working tree is converted
>   into the index format (clean filter, CRLF conversion, ...).
>   **Here, when commited with CRLF, the line endings should not be converted.**

Answer (score 3):

I would not allow my source control system to control my line endings. Auto crlf is false and showing diffs without the annoying ^M is done by setting core.whitespace to cr-at-eol. Now diff output will be nicer to read.

Comment: If I could have my own way I'd also work with `lf`, but I'm using my **git** repo to work with my organisation's **svn** in which the line endings are required to by `crlf`. When I `git svn dcommit`, I don't want to push `lf` eols to the database.

I'm not finding any problems anywhere else working with `crlf` (I'm on Windows), `git diff` and `vim` won't show `^M` unless there's an inconsistency.

Comment: But this is at a cost of having the line endings stored differently in git vs svn. If you do that, you'll have friction. This is why I recommend autocrlf set to false and then just deal with the way diffs are displayed via core.whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try on a clean working directory:

```
git apply mychanges.patch
git diff -w > mychangesnows.patch
git reset --hard
git apply mychangesnows.patch
```

Comment: I expected this to work for me, but for some reason it didn't.  Instead, I was successful using : `git apply --whitespace=fix mychanges.patch`.  _**Bonus:** fewer commands!_

Comment: @blong, you should submit an answer.